# react native expo app icon is coming very zoom

Tags: react-native, expo, icons

App icon size is 1024x1024 which is expo standard but still app icon is comming very zommed.

I have tried to clear cache, deleted android android folder but that dosn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I made the icon with the size Expo recommends, even using their templates in Figma, but the App icon always comes out enlarged and wrong. Did you find a solution?